# How to insert an empty line before and after #, ##, ### through terminal

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed, terminal

I am using OSX El Capitan. I have a series of md files, file1.md, file2.md, file3.md etc. Some of `# ## ###`  has no line before or after. This breaks when I convert to epub files.

Sample:

```
<a name="introduction"></a>
## Introduction
...
some texts
### Next topic
...
some texts
### Topic 3
some texts

pandoc -S -o Laravel-doc-5.2.epub *.md
```

Outputs do not have h1 or h2 tag.

```
## Introduction
```

So I want to insert an empty line before and after `# or ## or ###` a line **if there is no line**.

What I want is:

```
<a name="introduction"></a>

## Introduction

...
some texts

### Next topic

...
some texts

### Topic 3

some texts
```

How can I achieve this through the terminal or any method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following pattern might work as expected for `OS X`:

```
sed '/^#/{x;p;x;G;}' file.md
```

The command does an exchange, print, exchange, then get to add newlines above/below `#` lines.

↳ https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt

Comment: Ok, it print out ok but file itself didn't change anything. How to save it or modify the file as output?

Comment: I see; so you are wanting an in-place edit i presume. use `sed -i '' '/^#/{x;p;x;G;}' file.md` to save to the file after the changes. To output to a new file you can do `'sed '/^#/{x;p;x;G;}' file.md > newfile.md`.

Comment: @shin, Run `sed` with the `-i` option: `sed -i '' '/^#/{x;p;x;G;}' file.md`

Comment: Thanks. Can I use a wild card? `sed -i '' '/^#/{x;p;x;G;}' *.md` And it worked. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Sure, wildcards are fine; i might suggest using `./*.md` in-case you have any names with dashes. Otherwise when the command comes across a file with a `-` it might interpret it as an option.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you on a GNU system:

```
sed 's/^#\{1,3\}.*/\n&\n/' file
```

On OSX you'll need the following command:

```
sed 's/^#\{1,3\}.*/\'$'\n&\'$'\n'/' file
```

or simply

```
sed 's/^#\{1,3\}.*/
&
/' file
```

Sorry, I cannot test the commands on OSX, I'm referring to: http://nlfiedler.github.io/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac.html

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's because you are on MacOSX? Check this http://nlfiedler.github.io/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac.html I'm sorry, I cannot test it, but I've added the command for OSX

Comment: @shin, sed's regular expression syntax is slightly different from that understood by regexr.com

Comment: @shin indeed. If you want `sed` to change the file in place, use `sed -i .bak 'command'`. `-i` changes the file in place and creates a backup file with the ending `.bak`.

Comment: Sorry it was my misunderstanding. The second one print out ok. But I thought it modify the file as well. So when I check the file nothing was changed. That's why I wrote it didn't work. Now how can I save the file as outputs then??